# Jenkins manual trigger, how to display configuration variables from SVN on page

Tags: jenkins

I have all my test environment configurations stored in SVN in .properties files. I also have a Jenkins job that can deploy my artifacts to a specific test environment with delivery/build pipeline manual trigger. However, this can create a sense of uncertainty because I am never quite sure what configurations I deploy to the test environment as Jenkins does not automatically show them to you.

I noticed Jenkins offers parameterized builds, and offers you a page which lets you parameterize some values e.g. using some drop-down before triggering the build. My question is , would it be possible to have Jenkins display all the key/value pairs I have defined in my .properties file, and even let me change them? This way I could always review/edit my environment properties before actually making the deployment. Ofcourse, if I make changes then I need to remember to add them to SVN too... Thanks for your input!

Comment: Anything is possible with a plugin. Are you asking if you can do this without having to write something custom? (I think the answer to that would be no)

Comment: Yes, I am asking if this can be done without custom work :) I would assume that reading a text file from workspace and outputing it on a Jenkins page would be quite a common operation. That is why I would assume there is a plugin for this.